# Spark Cassandra write rows not shown in cqlsh

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, streaming

I am using Sparks Cassandra Connector to write streaming messages to Cassandra Column family. Even though the log is shown as Data being written to the table, upon querying the data, it is not shown.

Here is the Software Stack in action.

> Java 1.8, Cassandra 3.11.4, Spark 2.4.3

I am using the following code to write the data from dataset,

```
dataset.write().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
     .option("table", tableName)
     .option("keyspace", keySpace)
     .mode(SaveMode.Append).save();
```

the log message are indicating that the records are being written successfully as follows,

```
[Executor task launch worker for task 58915] INFO  2020-01-27 08:49:25,608 com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter  - Wrote 7 rows to keyspace.ssl_connections_1_2020 in 0.011 s.
[Executor task launch worker for task 58916] INFO  2020-01-27 08:49:25,612 com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter  - Wrote 9 rows to keyspace.ssl_connections_1_2020 in 0.011 s.
[Executor task launch worker for task 58919] DEBUG 2020-01-27 08:49:25,619 com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter  - Writing data partition to keyspace.ssl_connections_1_2020 in batches of BytesInBatch(1024)
```

Would appreciate any help in the direction in debugging the issue.

Edit Structure of Table

```
connections_timeseries_1_2020 (
    srcip text,
    day int,
    hour int,
    id text,
    connectionstate text,
    connectiontimestamp timestamp,
    dayofweek int,
    destip text,
    destipbytes double,
    destmac text,
    destpackets double,
    destport int,
    duration double,
    history text,
    localdest boolean,
    localsrc boolean,
    minute int,
    missedbytes double,
    month int,
    protocol text,
    receivedbytes double,
    reportedsensor text,
    services list<text>,
    srcipbytes double,
    srcmac text,
    srcpackets double,
    srcport int,
    transmittedbytes double,
    vlan int,
    weekofyear int,
    year int,
    PRIMARY KEY ((srcip, day), hour, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (hour ASC, id ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': '500'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

The rows are initially getting saved but are stopping upon date change and the type of messages is JSON which being transformed to datasets in Spark before saving it to Cassandra.

Comment: what is the table structure & what are data? Is all data not shown, or only some of them?

Comment: @alex Appreciate your quick response , updated the post per your queries.

Comment: @kishoregoud Can you check if both the client and DB servers are in sync w.r.t  time? I believe that might be the issue.